# How do I group an array based on a property value?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have two JavScript objects (POJO):

```
var first_original = [
  {group: "A", title: "foo1"},
  {group: "A", title: "foo2"},
  {group: "A", title: "foo3"},
  {group: "A", title: "foo4"},
  {group: "B", title: "foo5"},
  {group: "B", title: "foo6"},
  {group: "B", title: "foo7"}
];
var second_original = [
  {group: null, title: "bar1"},
  {group: null, title: "bar2"},
  {group: null, title: "bar3"},
  {group: null, title: "bar4"},
  {group: null, title: "bar5"},
  {group: null, title: "bar6"},
  {group: null, title: "bar7"}
];
```

I'm having difficulty conceptualizing how I can *map* them to the following structure:

```
var first_copy = [
  {
    header: "A",
    items: [
      {group: "A", title: "foo1"},
      {group: "A", title: "foo2"},
      {group: "A", title: "foo3"},
      {group: "A", title: "foo4"}
    ]
  },
  {
    header: "B",
    items: [
      {group: "B", title: "foo5"},
      {group: "B", title: "foo6"},
      {group: "B", title: "foo7"}
    ]
  }
];
var second_copy = [
  {
    header: null,
    items: [
      {group: null, title: "bar1"},
      {group: null, title: "bar2"},
      {group: null, title: "bar3"},
      {group: null, title: "bar4"},
      {group: null, title: "bar5"},
      {group: null, title: "bar6"},
      {group: null, title: "bar7"}
    ]
  }
];
```

I've attempted to use `.forEach()`:

```
function getRemappedObject(contentList) {
  val lastGroup    = null;
  var currentIndex = 0;
  var groups       = [];
  contentList.forEach(function(item) {
    if (!groups[currentIndex]) {
      groups.push({items: [item]});
    } else {
      groups[currentIndex].items.push(item);
    }
    groups[currentIndex].header = item.group;
    if (item.group && item.group !== lastGroup) {
      lastGroup = item.group;
      currentIndex++;
    }
  });
  return groups;
}
```

But this fails miserably at the header portion of the spec. I think it's lack of sleep but I was curious if there was a better approach. I'd like to solve it without Underscore or Lodash. ECMAScript 5 or 6 please.

How do I map the above structures to the expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use another *Array* to keep track of the header values;

```
function organise(arr) {
    var headers = [], // an Array to let us lookup indicies by group
        objs = [],    // the Object we want to create
        i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
        j = headers.indexOf(arr[i].group); // lookup
        if (j === -1) { // this entry does not exist yet, init
            j = headers.length;
            headers[j] = arr[i].group;
            objs[j] = {};
            objs[j].header = arr[i].group;
            objs[j].items = [];
        }
        objs[j].items.push( // create clone
            {group: arr[i].group, title: arr[i].title}
        );
    }
    return objs;
}

var first_copy = organise(first_original);
```

If you can assume that the groupings will always be a *string* i.e. never `null` you can do it more efficiently by key rather than an indexOf lookup

---

ES6 would probably let you do it more like the other solutions here via e.g. a [**Map**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) (*WeakMap* does not permit primitives as keys)

Comment: The data model used to be that `item.group` was either all null (resulting with an array of one element and the header property as undefined/null) or a string for elements that started the group and null for the other items in the group till the next string. But I since changed it so that `item.group` remained either a string (sorted) or always null (not mixing).