# How to extract JSON data in a particular column in an excelsheet in angular 4

Tags: javascript, json, excel, angular, typescript

I need help in extracting JSON data in an excel sheet in angular 4. I know this question is answered earlier. But my issue is bit different. For a common id, all the note and case_ worked related to that particular id should in single row in the excel sheet.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/json-data-to-excel

It would be great if I can get any help..

```js
data: any = [{
    case_worked: "abc",
    note: "Test",
    id: "1234"
  },
  {
    case_worked: "def",
    note: "test 1",
    id: "1234"
  },
  {
    case_worked: "def",
    note: "Test 2",
    id: "3456"
  }];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can group the data based on id. Ref - https://stackoverflow.com/a/29224580/3409030

```js
constructor(private excelService: ExcelService) {
    this.groupData = this.organise(this.data);
  }

organise(arr) {
    var headers = [], // an Array to let us lookup indicies by group
      objs = [],    // the Object we want to create
      i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
      j = headers.indexOf(arr[i].id); // lookup
      if (j === -1) { // this entry does not exist yet, init
        j = headers.length;
        headers[j] = arr[i].id;
        objs[j] = {};
        objs[j].id = arr[i].id;
        objs[j].data = [];
      }
      objs[j].data.push( // create clone
        {
          group: arr[i].id, case_worked: arr[i].case_worked,
          note: arr[i].note, id: arr[i].id
        }
      );
    }
    return objs;
  }
```

```html
<tr *ngFor="let item of groupData">
  <td>
      <div *ngFor="let data of item.data">
        <span>{{data.case_worked}}</span>
        </div> 
    </td>
    <td>
      <div *ngFor="let data of item.data">
        <span>{{data.note}}</span>
        </div> 
    </td>
  <td>{{item.id}}</td>
 </tr>
```

Comment: Hi @Pranesh U H, thank you for a quick reply. Grouping is fine but how can I extract that data in excel sheet. My doubt is in a single row, for a single id, all the data related to that id should be in the same row.

Comment: @ShradhaMallick

Comment: @ShradhaMallick the xlsx Utlity function json_to_sheet works only on flat JSON. So either you have to bare with repeated row ids or group data as string. Check console in https://codesandbox.io/s/x270ojmy6z