# Filter an array by object and select properties as new array in Typescript

Tags: javascript, filter

I have an array with the following values

```
 [
    {
        id: 101,
        name: 'Alex',
        tg: 'REV006',
       
    },
    {
        id: 101,
        name: 'Alex',
        tg: 'REV002',
       
    },
    {
        id: 101,
        name: 'Alex',
        tg: 'REV001',
       
    },
    {
        id: 104,
        name: 'Dave',
        tg: 'REV003',
       
    },
    {
        id: 101,
        name: 'Alex',
        tg: 'REV005',
       
    },
    {
        id: 108,
        name: 'Arun',
        tg: 'REV005',
       
    },
   
]
```

I would like to get filter by id and
make an array for the tg property it as below format.
In other words I need to make the tg as array  for based on the id and avoid duplication of arrays by making it in single array ).

```
[
{
    id: 101,
    name: 'Alex',
    tg: ['REV006','REV002','REV001','REV005']

},
{
    id: 104,
    name: 'Dave',
    tg: ['REV003'],

},

{
    id: 108,
    name: 'Arun',
    tg: ['REV005'],

},
```

]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I group an array based on a property value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29224505/how-do-i-group-an-array-based-on-a-property-value)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I aggregate/group an Array of Objects by property value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57262228/how-can-i-aggregate-group-an-array-of-objects-by-property-value)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this

```js
const data = [
    {
        id: 101,
        name: 'Alex',
        tg: 'REV006',

    },
    {
        id: 101,
        name: 'Alex',
        tg: 'REV002',

    },
    {
        id: 101,
        name: 'Alex',
        tg: 'REV001',

    },
    {
        id: 104,
        name: 'Dave',
        tg: 'REV003',

    },
    {
        id: 101,
        name: 'Alex',
        tg: 'REV005',

    },
    {
        id: 108,
        name: 'Arun',
        tg: 'REV005',

    },

]

const result = Object.values(data.reduce((acc, { id, name, tg }) => {
  if (!acc[id]) {
    acc[id] = { id, name, tg: [tg] };
  } else {
    acc[id].tg.push(tg);
  }
  return acc;
}, {}));

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Works perfectly as expected